# Angular link FormControl to object field

Tags: angular

My code has a `FormGroup` and an object that have pretty much the same fields:

Model:

```
class User {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  email: string,
}
```

Component:

```
/** User object, to easily manipulate */
user = new User();

/** User FormGroup, to use on form fields */
userForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
  lastName: new FormControl(''),
  email: new FormControl(''),
})
```

My question is, is there any good way to link the fields from the object to the form control? So I have only to set one of them and not care that the other may be out of date.

> I thought of setting the `formControlName` and `ngModel` in the same field, but this is deprecated as of Angular 6.

Comment: you can use form.valueChanges to assign changed value to the user object.im not sure about the other way around

Answer (score 2):

You will have to patch the form data to the object and vice versa.

You can have you form like this

```
<form class="form" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="userForm.valid && onSubmit()"></form>
```

And in .ts

For patching the value to form

```
this.userForm.patchValue(this.user);
```

And From the from to the object

```
OnSubmit(){
 this.user= Object.assign(this.user, this.userForm.value);
}
```

Comment: you can also use spread operator to make a "copy": `this.user={...this.userForm.value}`

Comment: Thanks! your solution for the object to the form worked :)
But for the other way around I went with the solution from @Hansaka Sandaruwan with using `form.valueChanges`

Answer (score -1):

According to [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms#bind-input-controls-to-data-properties), you can bind them using `[ngModel]` directive. For example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" name="firstName">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" name="lastName">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email">
```

Comment: @M Fuat, the question is about ReactiveForms. Your answer use Template driven form. They are two very, very different approaches to solve a problem